# why i can't reverse a list of list in python

Tags: python, list, reverse, map-function

i wanted to do something like this but this code return list of None (i think it's because list.reverse() is reversing the list in place):

```
map(lambda row: row.reverse(), figure)
```

i tried this one, but the reversed return an iterator :

```
map(reversed, figure)
```

finally i did something like this , which work for me , but i don't know if it's the right solution:

```
def reverse(row):
    """func that reverse a list not in place"""
    row.reverse()
    return row

map(reverse, figure)
```

if someone has a better solution that i'm not aware of please let me know

kind regards,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list.reverse does not return list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/list-reverse-does-not-return-list)

Answer (score 27):

The *mutator* methods of Python's mutable containers (such as the `.reverse` method of lists) almost invariably return `None` -- a few return one useful value, e.g. the `.pop` method returns the popped element, but the key concept to retain is that none of those mutators returns the mutated container: rather, the container mutates **in-place** and the return value of the mutator method is *not* that container.  (This is an application of the [CQS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation) principle of design -- not quite as fanatical as, say, in Eiffel, the language devised by Bertrand Meyer, who also invented CQS, but that's just because in Python "practicality beats purity, cfr `import this`;-).

Building a list is often costlier than just building an iterator, for the overwhelmingly common case where all you want to do is *loop* on the result; therefore, built-ins such as `reversed` (and all the wonderful building blocks in the `itertools` module) return iterators, *not* lists.

But what if you therefore have an iterator `x` but really truly need the equivalent *list* `y`?  Piece of cake -- just do `y = list(x)`.  To make a new instance of type `list`, you *call* type `list` -- this is such a general Python idea that it's even more crucial to retain than the pretty-important stuff I pointed out in the first two paragraphs!-)

So, the code for your specific problem is really very easy to put together based on the crucial notions in the previous paragraphs:

```
[list(reversed(row)) for row in figure]
```

Note that I'm using a list comprehension, **not** `map`: as a rule of thumb, `map` should only be used as a last-ditch optimization when there is *no* need for a `lambda` to build it (if a `lambda` is involved then a listcomp, as well as being clearer as usual, also tends to be faster anyway!-).

Once you're a "past master of Python", if your profiling tells you that this code is a bottleneck, you can then know to try alternatives such as

```
[row[::-1] for row in figure]
```

applying a negative-step slicing (aka "Martian Smiley") to make reversed copies of the rows, knowing it's usually faster than the `list(reversed(row))` approach.  But -- unless your code is meant to be maintained only by yourself or somebody at least as skilled at Python -- it's a defensible position to use the simplest "code from first principles" approach except where profiling tells you to push down on the pedal.  (Personally I think the "Martian Smiley" is important enough to avoid applying this good general philosophy to this specific use case, but, hey, reasonable people could differ on this very specific point!-).

Answer (score 8):

You can also use a slice to get the reversal of a single list (*not* in place):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[::-1]
[4, 3, 2, 1]
```

So something like:

```
all_reversed = [lst[::-1] for lst in figure]
```

...or...

```
all_reversed = map(lambda x: x[::-1], figure)
```

...will do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
reversed_lists = [list(reversed(x)) for x in figure]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map(lambda row: list(reversed(row)), figure)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply do

```
for row in figure:
    row.reverse()
```

to change each row in place.