# How can I get a reversed copy of a list (avoid a separate statement when chaining a method after .reverse)?

Tags: python, functional-programming

This code fails:

```
fCamel = 'F'
bCamel = 'B'
gap = ' '

k = ['F', ' ', 'B', 'F']

def solution(formation):
    return ((formation.index(bCamel) > (len(formation) - 1 - (formation.reverse()).index(fCamel))))

solution(k)
```

I get an exception that says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'`.

I know that **the problem is that `list.reverse()` returns `None`**, modifying the list in-place. I want to use `.index` on the reversed list. Is there a way I can avoid using a separate statement to reverse the list before indexing into it? How?

Comment: What happens if the elements you are looking for aren't in the list?  Perhaps if you describe what you are trying to do we can help you make a better more "pythonic" solution.

Comment: I'm trying to solve that camel puzzle in python so I can learn the language a little. Basically, this function should return true if all the 'F's are on the left hand side of the first 'B'.

Comment: Just wondering. I see more and more questions that remain without upvotes. This seems like an interesting question, if a simple one, to me. Why don't people vote for questions a bit more? I often see high volumes of votes for the replies, meaning that the question at least had the potential to bring interesting solutions or discussions, but not one vote for the questions itself. Seems odd to me (O_O) Cheers!

Comment: @Morlock: I often wonder that too, I always try to up vote any interesting question.

Comment: list.reverse does not return list.  That's a fact.  What's your question?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `reversed(formation)` to return a reverse iterator of `formation`.  When you call `formation.reverse()` it does an in place reversal of the list and returns None.

EDIT:

I see what you are trying to do now, in my opinion it's easier to just do this with a list comprehension:

```
def solution(formation):
    return len([k for k in formation[formation.index(bCamel)+1:] if k == fCamel]) == 0
```

This basically looks at all the elements after the first `bCamel` and collects all the elements that have the value `fCamel`.  If that list has a length == 0 you have a solution.

Here's a few examples:

```
>>> k = ['F','F','B','B','F']
>>> solution(k)
False
>>> k = ['F','F','B','B','B']
>>> solution(k)
True
>>> k = ['F','F','B','F','F','B','B']
>>> solution(k)
False
>>>
```

Comment: This won't work on the OP's unmodified code, since "reversed" doesn't return a list, but an iterator (which doesn't have the "index" method).

Comment: Yeah, I remembered that and adjusted my comment.  He would definitely have to modify his code a bit to get it to work the way he wants.

Comment: I do understand that. But, it would have made much more sense if it returned the reversed object (this? or what do you call it in python?) also right? Is there any other function that does that? Otherwise I'd have another couple of lines :(

Comment: If you absolutely must keep it in one line, you can use something like `list(reversed(formation))`. But you're likely coming from other languages, and you'll soon learn that Python doesn't favour creating a bunch of similar methods just for the sake of one-liners :)

Comment: I suppose he can also just use (len(formation) - 1 - list[::-1].index(fCamel)) but that's quite ugly too.

Comment: GWW: Not at all; some_list[::-1] is quite a common idiom for reversing a list :)

Comment: @rbp I'm mostly referring to the (len(formation) - 1 - ..) part.  I love using list[::-1] :)

Comment: Was `fCamel not in formation[formation.index(bCamel)+1:]` not yet possible in 2010?

Answer (score 63):

You can use slicing to return the reversed list:

```
l[::-1]
```

Comment: would be great if put at last "l = [...] / print(l) / print(l[::-1] "

Comment: This is the real answer to this question. It returns a reversed list in-place so you can do it inside of list comprehensions.

Answer (score 8):

To build on GWW's answer, if you want this code to work as is you would just do `list(reversed(formation))`.  If you really want to be able to use `formation.reverse()` instead, you would have to subclass `list`:

```
>>> class ReversableList(list):
...     def reverse(self):
...         return list(reversed(self))
... 
>>> x = ReversableList([1,2,3])
>>> x.reverse()
[3, 2, 1]
```

Whether or not this is advisable is another question of course.

Answer (score 6):

list.reverse reverses inplace. That is:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> l
[3, 2, 1]
```

Please consult the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/), things like these are laid out there. You can also try the 'help' built-in:

> > > > help(l.reverse) Help on built-in function reverse:
>
> reverse(...)
>       L.reverse() -- reverse *IN PLACE*

Answer (score 5):

I just came across this problem and wanted to clarify some things for users new to python coming from a javascript background.

In javascript, a.reverse() reverses in place and also returns the array when called.

Javascript:

```
var a = [2, 3 ,4]
console.log(a.reverse())
// outputs [4, 3, 2]
console.log(a)
// outputs [4, 3, 2]
```

In python, **a.reverse() reverses in place, but does not return the array.** This is what caused confusion for me.

In python:

```
a = [2, 3, 4]
a.reverse()
print(a)
# outputs [4, 3, 2]
# can't do print(a.reverse())
```

Comment: This does not answer the question - it only *explains* the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

the following changes will be effective:

```
NumSet={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
NumList = list(NumSet)
NumList.reverse()
print(NumList)
```

- avoid using the assignment operator after the initial assignment as lists are mutable types.
- Using = operator with a method..(eg NumList = NumSet.reverse()) will cause the method to overwrite list with a blank, thereby effectively clearing the list. That's why list becomes a NoneType. 
  Methods are functions and doesn't actually have its own value, thus the blank.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches to the problem shown in the OP. A summary:

- Use a different technique that gives you a reversed copy of the list, so that this *expression* can be used in place. The two main ways to do this are `formation[::-1]` and `list(reversed(formation))` (see [How to reverse a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128)).

Analogous solutions exist to replace other list functionality, for example:

```
# mylist.append(1)
# mylist.index(1)
(mylist + [1]).index(1) # note that the value is wrapped in another list

# mylist.extend(anotherlist)
# mylist.index(1)
(mylist + anotherlist).index(1)

# mylist.sort()
# mylist.index(1)
sorted(mylist).index(1)
```

- Bite the bullet and use a separate statement anyway. `Simple is better than complex`; good Python style often avoids long expressions like `((formation.index(bCamel) > (len(formation) - 1 - (formation.reverse()).index(fCamel))))` because it's hard to follow the logic. Keep in mind that since we *are still using an in-place method*, the original `formation` is still modified. This can be useful, but it often causes problems.
- (**Please do not use this in real code.**) We can abuse conditional expressions to make the assignment happen as a side effect:

```
def solution(formation):
    return formation.index(bCamel) > (
         len(formation) - 1 - (formation.reverse() or formation).index(fCamel)
    )
```

The idea is that since `formation.reverse()` will return `None`, which [is falsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695), so `or` is forced not to short-circuit, and [will evaluate to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47007680) `formation` - *after* the reversal has occurred as a side effect.

Other expressions can have the same net effect, e.g. `[formation, formation.reverse()][0]`. The idea is to write something that is an *expression* that includes the `.reverse` call, but *evaluates to* the original list object. We can be arbitrarily creative here - but again, `Simple is better than complex`. Please don't do these things.

Again, keep in mind that *this will still modify the original list*, which may impact on future calculations.

- Rework the logic to avoid the need to reverse the list. The code tries to reverse the list, search in the reversed list for the index of the first match, and then subtract that result from `len(formation) - 1` - the overall effect of this is to search for the index of the **last** match. Lists don't have a method for that, but strings do; and as it happens, all our elements are single-character strings. We could solve the problem more simply by representing the formation with a string:

```
def solution(formation):
    return formation.index(bCamel) > formation.rindex(fCamel)

solution('F BF')
```

Alternately, we can conceive of the problem differently: "Is there a `fCamel` in the part of the list that follows the first `bCamel`?" The accepted answer shows using a list comprehension to iterate over "the part of the list that follows the first `bCamel`", making a list of all the `fCamel`s there, and checking whether that list is non-empty. But we can do it much more simply:

```
# works with either the string or list input
def solution(formation):
    return fCamel not in formation[formation.index(bCamel)+1:]
```

(There are even more clever ways to write this, such as Stefan's answer using iterators.)

Solutions like this are *specific to the problem solved by the code*, and don't answer the *question in general*. However, it is often possible to find similar solutions in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Not super beautiful, but I did not find the equivalent in the precedent answers. If the speed or memory costs are low (the list is not very long or the operation not repeated a huge amount of times), this is pretty straight forward and even easier to read.

```
import copy

fCamel = 'F'
bCamel = 'B'
gap = ' '

k = ['F', ' ', 'B', 'F']

def solution(formation):
    rev_formation = copy.copy(formation)
    rev_formation.reverse()
    return ((formation.index(bCamel) > (len(formation) - 1 -
            (rev_formation).index(fCamel))))
```

Comment: OP specifically asked about how to avoid using a temporary (here, `rev_formation`).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't provide a solution to the F _ B F pattern problem, but **it does address the issue of python not returning a list** when you use .reverse().

This is how I got around it:

```
chars = ['a', '-', 'c']
chars2 = [] + chars
chars2.reverse()
totalChars = chars + chars2
```

totalChars returns a-cc-a, which is what I wanted, AND chars2 is a list, not a pointer to chars.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for you, but this works for me:

```
list = [1,2,3]
print([list, list.reverse()][0])
```

The reason list.reverse() returns None is because the function doesn't return anything.

Using your code:

```
fCamel = 'F'
bCamel = 'B'
gap = ' '

k = ['F', ' ', 'B', 'F']

def solution(formation):
    return ((formation.index(bCamel) > (len(formation) - 1 - ([formation, formation.reverse()][0]).index(fCamel))))

print(solution(k))
```

Comment: It's pretty easy to understand why it works: `[list, list.reverse()]` reverses the list in-place, and makes a list that contains the reversed list as well as the return value `None`. Then `[0]` gets the first element, which is the reversed list.

Answer (score 0):

Title question is already answered, but for what you were really after:

> Basically, this function should return true if **all the 'F's are on the left hand side of the first 'B'**

That's the same as **there's no 'B' followed by an 'F'**. Nice way to check this is with an iterator:

```
def solution(formation):
    it = iter(formation)
    return not (bCamel in it and fCamel in it)
```

Some advantages:

- Unlike every `formation.index(...)` solution it doesn't crash if the searched value isn't there.
- Takes only O(1) extra space (unlike the solutions making a reversed copy of the list).
- Touches every element at most *once* and stops as soon as possible. Even has O(1) time best case (even with millions of elements, if the list starts with `['B', 'F',` then it stops right there).