# Unable to reverse lists in Python, getting "Nonetype" as list

Tags: python, list

I have a `.py` file that takes a list, finds the lowest number, puts it into a new array, removes the lowest number from the first array, and repeats until the original array returns contains no more items:

```
def qSort(lsort):
    listlength = len(lsort)
    sortedlist = list()
    if listlength == 0:
        return lsort
    else:
        while listlength > 0:
            lmin = min(lsort)
            sortedlist.append(lmin)
            lsort.remove(lmin)
            listlength = len(lsort)
        return sortedlist
```

Now another `.py` file imports the `qSort` and runs it on some list, saving it to a variable. Then I try to use the `.reverse()` command on the list and I end up getting it as a `NoneType`. I try to use `reversed()`, but all it does is say `"<listreverseiterator object at 0xSomeRandomHex>"`:

```
from qSort import qSort #refer to my first Pastebin

qSort = qSort([5,42,66,1,24,5234,62])
print qSort #this prints the sorted list
print type(qSort) #this prints <type 'list'>
print qSort.reverse() #this prints None
print reversed(qSort) #this prints "<listreverseiterator object at 0xSomeRandomHex>"
```

Can anyone explain why I can't seem to reverse the list, no matter what I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list.reverse does not return list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/list-reverse-does-not-return-list)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As jcomeau mentions, the `.reverse()` function changes the list in place.  It does not return the list, but rather leaves `qSort` altered.

If you want to 'return' the reversed list, so it can be used like you attempt in your example, you can do a slice with a direction of -1

So replace `print qSort.reverse()` with `print qSort[::-1]`

---

You should know slices, its useful stuff.  I didn't really see a place in the tutorial where it was all described at once, (http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists doesn't really cover everything) so hopefully here are some illustrative examples.

Syntax is: `a[firstIndexInclusive:endIndexExclusive:Step]`

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> a[7:] #seventh term and forward
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> a[:11] #everything before the 11th term
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a[::2] # even indexed terms.  0th, 2nd, etc
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> a[4:17]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> a[4:17:2]
[4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16]
>>> a[::-1]
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> a[19:4:-5]
[19, 14, 9]
>>> a[1:4] = [100, 200, 300] #you can assign to slices too
>>> a
[0, 100, 200, 300, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: "Slices"? You're speaking Greek right now. However, your method works and it works with fewer keystrokes, so it's good for me.

Comment: slices let you take a piece of an array.  it works like `a[beginIndexIncluded:endIndexExcluded:Step]`   `a[0:4]` gives the list with terms 0 thru 3 of a.  `a[3::2]` gives the list with term 3, 5, 7... to the end.  `a[::-1]` includes all elements of a, but starts with the last one and ends with the first (reversal)

Comment: +1, an accepted answer deserves an upvote, and I agree that's the best solution

Comment: Oh, wow. That's really useful. I just learning Python today, so I'm not very knowledgeable on it yet.

Comment: That makes a ton of sense now.

Comment: Haha, nope. That beats trying to hamfist something with `for x in range()`

Comment: Sure, but why doesn't `.reverse()` just change the list in place and return it as well?
Since it would return just a reference and not a copy this can't be too expensive...
Returning `None` is useless, returning a reference to the list could be useful in some cases...

Answer (score 13):

list.reverse() reverses in-place and returns nothing (None). so you don't say:

```
mylist = mylist.reverse()
```

you say:

```
mylist.reverse()
```

or alternatively:

```
mylist = list(reversed(mylist))
```

Comment: To create an iterator that will loop over the list in reverse order, use the `reversed` function: `reversed(mylist)` returns a list.

Comment: @Samir: reversed(mylist) returns, as you first said, an iterator, and not a list.

Answer (score 5):

The `reverse()` `list` method sorts the list in place and returns `None` to remind you of that (according to note 7 in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=reverse#mutable-sequence-types)). The built-in `reversed()` function returns an *iterator* object, which can be turned into a `list` object by passing it to the `list()` constructor function like this: `list(reversed(qSort))`. You can accomplish the same thing by creating a slice with a *step* size of negative one so it goes backwards, i.e `qSort[::-1]`.

BTW, `list`'s also have a `sort()` method (but be careful, it also returns `None` ;-).

Answer (score -1):

l5= [60,70,77]

myl2 = list(reversed(l5))

print(myl2)

**or**

mylist2 =[50,60,80,90]

mylist2.reverse()

print(mylist2)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).