# returning the list reversed

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, reversing

i have this question:

*Write a function reverse3(nums) that takes a list of ints of length 3 called `nums` and returns a new list with the elements in reverse order, so [1, 2, 3] becomes [3, 2, 1].*

i solved it by:

```
def reverse3(nums):
    return [nums[2]] + [nums[1]] + [nums[0]]
```

however, the answer is straight foward. My main question, how do i get `nums` reversed, when i don't know how many ints there are in `nums`?.

I've got this:
`nums[::-1]` which does return `nums` reversed.but i'm looking for a different way. probably looping?

Iv'e tried this:

```
def reverse3(nums):
    return reversed(nums)
```

which returns: `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x10151ff90>` #location?

Comment: See also [python - list.reverse does not return list? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/list-reverse-does-not-return-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) returns an iterator. If you want to get a list object, use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list):

```
>>> def reverse3(nums):
...     return list(reversed(nums))
... 
>>> reverse3([4,5,6])
[6, 5, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

List has a built in reverse function

```
list.reverse()
```

so you could use

```
nums.reverse()
```

However, if you want to write your own function you would need to do a reverse iteration to another list.

Something like-

```
def revList(nums)
   i = len(mums) -1
   while i >= 0:
      revNums[i] = nums.pop()
      i = i - 1
   return(revNums)
```