# trying to figure out what's wrong with my code regarding lists?

Tags: python, list, ide, geany

So I just started coding and I chose python. I was working with lists and I noticed something kinda odd.

```
wishPlaces = ["Tokyo","Hong Kong","New York","Paris","London"]

print("\n"+str(wishPlaces.reverse()))
```

if I write it that way, then once executed it shows "None" as a result (I use geany IDE)

But it's okay when I write:

```
wishPlaces = ["Tokyo","Hong Kong","New York","Paris","London"]


wishPlaces.reverse()
print("\n"+str(wishPlaces))
```

Can somebody help me by telling what's wrong with the previous line of code?

Comment: `wishPlaces.reverse()` doesn't return anything, so...

Comment: `reverse` reverses the elements in place with no return, that is why you get `None` as an output in your first example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list.reverse does not return list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/list-reverse-does-not-return-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list iteration instead:

```
wishPlaces = ["Tokyo","Hong Kong","New York","Paris","London"]
wishPlaces = wishPlaces[-1:0:-1]
print(wishPlaces)
```

The `[-1:0:-1]` is an iterating syntax. First value is starting index; `-1` represents the last item of your list. Second defines the finishing index. Third value defines step; `-1` is reversed.

**Final code:**

```
wishPlaces = ["Tokyo","Hong Kong","New York","Paris","London"]

print("\n"+wishPlaces[-1:0:-1])
```

*Note that you dont need to convert list items to string*

*Also `print` function automatically prints new line to console window*

Answer (score 0):

The `reverse()` method is an in place method. This means that it doesn't return anything, it just modifies the list in place. That's why you use `wishPlaces.reverse()` to modify `wishPlaces` and **NOT** `wishPlaces=wishPlaces.reverse()` .

When you have `print("\n"+str(wishPlaces.reverse()))`, you are telling python to print what `wishPlaces.reverse()` is **returning**, and what that method returns is `None` (a Nonetype object). When you modify `wishPlaces` in place using the `.reverse()` method and then print `wishPlaces`, things work as expected because you've actually modified `wishPlaces`.