# Python: List Reversing on One Line

Tags: python

```
ls = list(range(10))
ls.reverse()
print(ls)
```

Why does this work in producing a list that counts backwards from 9 not but not this:

```
ls = list(range(10)).reverse()
print(ls)
```

These last two lines prints this instead:

```
None
```

Shouldn't they be the same thing?

Comment: because `.reverse` works in-place, and so by convention it returns `None`. There is no reason to believe they should be the same thing. They can and do work differently. Note, you can just do `list(reversed(range(10))`

Answer (score 1):

No, because `list.reverse()` returns `None` since it reverses the list in place. See the [list documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

You could use `reversed()` like so:

```
countdown = list(reversed(range(10)))
print(countdown)
```

See the [reversed documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed)

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/list-reverse-does-not--list)