# Reverse in python lists not working as expected

Tags: python-3.x, list, reverse

```
os = ['Windows', 'macOS', 'Linux']
print('Original List:', os)
o=os.reverse()
print('Updated List:', o)
```

the output is  None!
why doesnt the assignment of reverse to o gives me a reversed list?

i also used

```
os.reverse
```

and then simply printed it and it worked! then why does the assignment of the same to o gives me nothing? pretty confused over it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [list.reverse does not return list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691/list-reverse-does-not-return-list)

Comment: The `reverse` method doesn't return a list. It modifies the list in-place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list method reverse does not return anything, so assigning a variable using list.reverse() gives you an empty variable.

Try:

```
os = ['Windows', 'macOS', 'Linux']
print('Original List:', os)
os.reverse()
print('Updated List:', os)
```

As you can see, the method reverses the list.
what does work is:

```
os = ['Windows', 'macOS', 'Linux']
print('Original List:', os)
o = os
o.reverse()
print('Updated List:', o)
```