# How do I reverse tuples in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

> Note; This is a self Q&A. Please see my answer below.

Given a list of tuples:

```
l = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
```

I'd like to find the quickest and simplest way to reverse each individual tuple in `x`, so that I get:

```
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794486/why-i-cant-reverse-a-list-of-list-in-python

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
l2 = [t[::-1] for t in l]
```

Use standard negative-step slicing `t[::-1]` to get the reverse of a tuple, and a list comprehension to get that for each tuple.

Comment: it would need converting to `tuple` to get the result you're expecting, but that's minor.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Look at the number of down votes on this question. I'm sitting at 450 rep today, I'm not going to gain anything from this. Seriously, asking questions is basically shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: you got rep for your own answer though. And I don't agree with you about shooting yourself in the foot (that may be true for meta...): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223125/should-i-avoid-converting-to-a-string-if-a-value-is-already-a-string

Answer (score 9):

This is quite simple actually, and there are a few ways, the simplest being a list comprehension. To reverse 2-tuples, just unpack them and swap:

```
[(y, x) for x, y in l]
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

To reverse n-tuples, you can slice in reverse using tuple slicing (`[::-1]`):

```
[x[::-1] for x in l]
# [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 5)]
```

Comment: Did you just write that answer to your your own question within a minute of posting question?

Comment: @PhilippeOger: There's an option to post the answer along with the question. (Also, self-answered questions are fine.)

Comment: can anyone tell me what is that In and out?

Comment: @Vicrobot erm, what In and Out \*whistles innocently\*

Comment: @coldspeed Was that simply input and output of interpreter; or any syntax of python?

Comment: @coldspeed..........   Also you mentioned that you was at 450 rep; that time; and now even in less than a year; in the list of top growing person on this site;... What's the source of such growth???..**just for curiosity**

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this...

```
l=[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c'), (4, 'd'), (5, 'e')]
l=[tuple(reversed(t)) for t in l]
```